# How to get portion of string from 2 different strings and concat?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 strings `a` and `b` with `-` as delimiter, want to get 3rd string by concatenating the substring upto last `%` from `a` (which is `one-two-three-%whatever%` in below example) and from string `b`, drop the substring upto number of dashes found in resultant string (which is 4 in below e.g., that gives `bar-bazz`), I did this so far, is there a better way?

```
>>> a='one-two-three-%whatever%-foo-bar'
>>> b='1one-2two-3three-4four-bar-bazz'
>>> k="%".join(a.split('%')[:-1]) + '%-'
>>> k
'one-two-three-%whatever%-'
>>> k.count('-')
4
>>> y=b.split("-",k.count('-'))[-1]
>>> y
'bar-bazz'
>>> k+y
'one-two-three-%whatever%-bar-bazz'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using Regex:

```
import re
a = 'one-two-three-%whatever%-foo-bar'
b = '1one-2two-3three-4four-bar-bazz'

part1 = re.findall(r".*%-",a)[0] # one-two-three-%whatever%-
num = part1.count("-") # 4
part2 = re.findall(r"\w+",b) # ['1one', '2two', '3three', '4four', 'bar', 'bazz']
part2 = '-'.join(part2[num:]) # bar-bazz

print(part1+part2) # one-two-three-%whatever%-bar-bazz
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first substring obtained from `a`, you can use `rsplit()`:

```py
k = a.rsplit('%', 1)[0] + '%-'
```

The rest look good to me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little shorter ?

```py
a = 'one-two-three-%whatever%-foo-bar'
b = '1one-2two-3three-4four-bar-bazz'

def merge (a,b):
    res = a[:a.rfind ('%')+1]+'-'
    return (res + "-".join (b.split ("-")[res.count ('-'):]))

print (merge (a,b) == 'one-two-three-%whatever%-bar-bazz')
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally get nervous when I need to manually increment indexes or concatenate bare strings.
This answer is pretty similar to hingev's, just without the additional concat/addition operators.

```
t = "-"
ix = list(reversed(a)).index("%")
t.join([s] + b.split(t)[len(a[:-ix].split(t)):])
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another possible answer:

```
def custom_merge(a, b):
    result = []
    idx = 0
    for x in itertools.zip_longest(a.split('-'), b.split('-')):
        result.append(x[idx])
        if x[0][0] == '%' == x[0][-1]:
            idx = 1
    return "-".join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is specific enough that you might be optimizing the wrong thing (a smaller piece of a bigger problem).  That being said, one way that feels easier to follow, and avoids some of the repeated linear traversals (splits and joins and counts) would be this:

```py
def funky_percent_join(a, b):
    split_a = a.split('-')
    split_b = b.split('-')
    breakpoint = 0  # len(split_a) if all of a should be used on no %
    for neg, segment in enumerate(reversed(split_a)):
        if '%' in segment:
            breakpoint = len(split_a) - neg
            break
    return '-'.join(split_a[:breakpoint] + split_b[breakpoint:])
```

and then

```
>>> funky_percent_join('one-two-three-%whatever%-foo-bar', '1one-2two-3three-4four-bar-bazz')
'one-two-three-%whatever%-bar-bazz'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(f"one-two-three-%{''.join(a.split('%')[1])}%")
```

that would work for the first, and then you could do the same for the second, and when you're ready to concat, you can do:

```
part1 = str(f"one-two-three-%{''.join(a.split('%')[1])}%")

part2 = str(f"-{''.join(b.split('-')[-2])}-{''.join(b.split('-')[-1])}")

result = part1+part2
```

this way it'll grab whatever you set the a/b variables to, provided they follow the same format.

but then again, why not do something like:

```
result = str(a[:-8] + b[22:])
```